# userform page if clause

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform and if condition to open and close the page on the main page as below.

```
  If a1 = "Fener" Then
    Myb1 = Getb1
    For Each b1 In Myb1
      Select Case b1
        Case "Z05", "Z54", "Z64"
          UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = True
        Case Else
          UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = False
      End Select
    Next b1
  Else
  UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = False
  End If
```

If I choose Z05 in my b1 list page5 gets visible. however, if I choose like Z06 (Z01 to Z99), page 5 closes. so to keep page5 open, have to choose the biggest Z for b1 and not choose any other b1 bigger than it.
if I remove the Else line then it seems working correctly. however, that time if I choose z05 and then I remove my selection page still visible.

so I could not succeed to keep it open while selecting as I wish.

getb1 is a function as below.

```
Function Getb1()
  ReDim b1(99)
  With UserForm1.ListBox4
    For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Selected(x) Then
        b1list = MyList & .List(x)
        b1(Z) = .List(x)
        Z = Z + 1
      End If
    Next x
  End With
  If Z > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve b1(Z - 1)
  End If
  Getb1 = b1
End Function
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to cultivate the habit of **all used variables declaring**. We can only deduce what is it about. What are ` Myb1` and `Getb1`? Arrays? If objects, they must be `Set`. If so, how do you match the 'array' elements with the mentioned "chosen Z05"?  Then, you start `For Each b1 In Myb1` and end it with `Next Dept`. And finally, you do not clearly describe what you expect from the above code? What "I choose Z05" does mean, since your code iterates between all `Myb1` items? Where from do you choose that "Z05" and how do you want using it during iteration?

Comment: I have a table (b1) that contains a list starting from Z01 to Z99 and only 3 of them need to trigger the page5. Even if at least 1 of them (Z05, Z54, Z64) is chosen on the list, the page5 need to keep visible to fill it. however, in that code even I choose 1 of them after any selection except these 3 page5 getting invisible again.

Comment: So, do you want making it visible after first occurrence of one of the three mentioned strings, you should only place `Exit For` after `UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = True`. Otherwise, the iteration will continue and the page in discussion will be visible or not **only according to the last cell value**.

Comment: actually, the below answer is advising the same as what you advised but getting the same result using the answer. in case I remove the first line at the answer, the page keeps visible but if any user chooses one of 3 mistakenly and then removes the selection, the page still is visible which I do not accept as a solution.

Comment: This only means that you are not able to explain what you need. I mean in which circumstances the page in discussion should be visible... I clearly mentioned the circumstances: "ir you want making it visible after first occurrence of one of the three mentioned strings". If this assumption is not correct, it must be your turn to clearly explain which is it...

Comment: user will select any Z from the list. if any one of the three is selected (no matter what is the order of the selected first or end or second selection) page needs to be visible. however, if the user mistakenly clicks one of the three and removes the selection page have to be invisible again. so as a result if any of the three is on the selection list page have to be visible if not in the list it should be invisible.

Comment: 1. I cannot see nowhere in your code **any selection**. 2. What `Myb1` is? Then, how `b1` to be a "list" as you say? If a list, what kind, in order to be the result of `Myb1` iteration? I cannot understand your question and I cannot help in such circumstances... I asked some clear questions in my first comment and you did not clarify anything. I/we only **tried guessing** what you want...

Comment: I'm guessing here, but sounds like any time they modify MyB1 you need to re-execute this code to check the selection, and react to that state.

Comment: thanks igittr. getb1 is a function and I have added it in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = False
If a1 = "Fener" Then
    Myb1 = Getb1
    For Each b1 In Myb1
      Select Case b1
        Case "Z05", "Z54", "Z64"
          UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Visible = True
          exit for
        Case Else
      End Select
    Next b1
  End If
```

Comment: thanks but the result is same